# Remover um estilo css com javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Boa tarde, sou novo em js e estou aprendendo!!
Eu tenho uma tag `<h1 class="title">`, essa classe "title" tem alguns estilos css `font-size; display-none; color`! o que eu queria fazer é quando clicasse em um botão que tenho também no HTML, eu gostaria de remover apenas o `display: none` da classe. eu até coloquei o  `display: none` em uma classe separada, para assim remover a classe toda, mas gostaria de saber como posso fazer removendo somente o `display: none` da classe title.
meu código:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const title = document.querySelector('.title');
 
btn.addEventListener('click'), () => {
   // removendo a classe toda
   title.classList.remove('title');
}
```

Obrigado!!

Comment: Algo como `title.style.display = "block"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: Ou algo como `title.classList.add('visible')`, e crie uma classe `visible` com `display: block`.

Comment: @Woss deu certo aqui, não tinha pensado nisso
obrigado!!

Comment: @bfavaretto minha intenção era evitar criar uma classe com somente o display: none/block, mas é uma opção boa, Obrigado!!

Answer (score -3):

eu acredito que o código anexado esta com erro ao passa os parâmetros no método "addEventListener", acredito que deveria ser da seguinte forma:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const title = document.querySelector('.title');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // removendo a classe toda
    title.classList.remove('title');
})
```

Outro problema que eu identifiquei é que quando é usado "title.classList.remove('title')", a variável "title" perde sua referência, acredito que voce deveria utilizar uma outra classe para alterar seu estilo, por exemplo "title-visible", assim seu código poderia ficar:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const title = document.querySelector('.title');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // removendo a classe toda
    title.classList.remove('title-visble');
})
```

No css:

```
.title {
    visibility: hidden;
 }

 .title {
    visibility: visible;
 }
```